# IntelliJ Idea Terminal broken with Windows 10

Tags: intellij-idea, windows-10

I've installed windows 10 and the terminal doesn't work in IntelliJ IDEA. I can open a new terminal, but I can't write.

[image]

Comment: Now it has been fixed, my version is: "#IU-141.2735 built on September 22, 2015"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to the [Terminal help](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/terminal.html) page comments, there is a [bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-135722) and a workaround:

> Terminal works in Windows 10 if you use legacy console. To do so, open
>   a command prompt window, right click on the title, then select
>   Properties. At the bottom, check "Use legacy console". Confirm the
>   dialog.  Go back to the IDE and launch a new Terminal. It should work.

Comment: Thanks seanhodges.
It worked for me with check "Use legacy console".

Comment: Now it has been fixed, my version is: "#IU-141.2735 built on September 22, 2015"

Answer (score 0):

The latest windows updates causes this work around to fail. After I updated KB3081448 on windows 10 my terminal stopped working again.