# Terminal on Android Studio not responding

Tags: android-studio

I updated to Android Studio 1.3 and to Windows 10 before that.

Now the issue I am facing is that my local embedded terminal in android studio has some how stopped responding to any kind of user input.

I have tried:

1. Restarting the android studio
2. Restarting the PC
3. Searching through Google for a solution

My Terminal settings

[image: Settings]

**Has anyone ever faced a similar issue?
Is it a Android Studio problem or a Windows problem?
How to solve it?**

You may suggest me to use the external terminal as that too will work fine. But that's not the answer I am looking for as it ruins the whole Android Studio experience.

Comment: Windows 10 comes with a heavily upgraded command shell; it is possible that Android Studio attempts to do something that is no longer supported in the new shell.. however this is not really a programming question

Comment: that is why i didn't tag it with android .. and chose android-studio according to stackoverflow tour guide, I can ask questions about development tools

Comment: Can you kind of point towards a directions to the stuff I can read , to get the solution to the issue ? @MikeDinescu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with IntelliJ and Windows 10 console.
Here is  a workaround from "IntelliJ Idea Terminal broken with Windows 10" thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31716623/703562

Works for Android Studio too.

The workaround:

1. Open a command-prompt window.
2. Right click on the title bar.
3. Select `Properties`, then check `Set legacy mode` box, and confirm the dialog.

Comment: Well, It needs to be added that Android Studio most probably will provide an update in future with the issue fixed, till that time the workaround is cool