# RubyMine Terminal Not Working Win10

Tags: windows, terminal, rubymine, windows-10

I recently installed RubyMine v7.1.4 on my Windows 10 machine. I loaded up an existing project and tried to open a terminal window inside RubyMine. When I first open the terminal it is blank and after a few minutes the standard prompt appears. But after the prompt has appeared, I cannot type anything into the terminal. The cursor blinks like it is waiting for input but I cannot type anything.

I am able to use a normal command prompt to run the commands I need to but I would like to get the terminal within RubyMine working. The settings for the terminal appear to be correct, it is pointing at "cmd.exe". I am not sure if it is relevant but my RubyMine installation is on my C: drive but the code repository is on my E: drive.

If you have any suggestions, they would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue, and discovered that it is also affecting IntelliJ, another JetBrains family IDE; the bug has been reported, but fortunately, you can force your Windows 10 console (full of new features, but perhaps buggy? https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908) to operate in 'legacy mode' while we wait for a formal fix, which will allow you to get your RubyMine terminals up and running again:

> Terminal works in Windows 10 if you use legacy console. To do so, open a
>   command prompt window, right click on the title, then select Properties. At 
>   the bottom, check "Use legacy console". Confirm the dialog. Go back to the IDE 
>   and launch a new Terminal. It should work.

All credit to: [IntelliJ Idea Terminal broken with Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716473/intellij-idea-terminal-broken-with-windows-10). | [JetBrains Bug Report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-135722).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I must have just not found the right combination of words to search to find this. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Amazing, thanks.  i had this issue too and it was driving me crazy!!